Reference check: Increasing variance is not optimal for Kelly betting
Kelly betting considers optimal betting when the player has finite resources. It can be shown that one is optimizing the following integral:
$$r(x)=\int \ln(r'(1-x)+xy)d\omega$$
For $r'$ the risk-free rate, $\omega$ the distribution of the returns, and $x$ is the fraction of their portfolio one bets. Let $x^*\in[0,\infty]$ denote the optimal fraction to bet, and $r^*=r(x^*)$.
I have proven that for any two distributions $\theta$ and $\omega$ such that:
$$
    \inf \text{supp}(\theta) = \inf \text{supp}(\omega) = 0
$$
If the raw moments all exist, and that they are all equal except $\theta$ has strictly larger second moment, then $\omega$ has a larger or equal $r^*$ than $\theta$. Equality only occurs iff $x^*=0$.
In English, this says that, under some reasonable technical conditions, if one is presented with two almost identical bets except one has larger variance, one should take the bet with lower variance.
In general, it can also be shown that larger odd moments and smaller even moments lead to higher returns.
I am wondering if this theorem is known, and if any other theorems of this sort are known.
